# Jetpack 'Blog Subscription' widget doesn't add emails to

Tags: widgets, blog, plugin-jetpack, subscription

I'm trying to use the jetpack 'Blog Subscriptions' widget, but any emails submitted with this widget aren't being added to the followers list. Verification emails aren't being sent to the subscribers either. How can I fix this problem?

Note: I've correctly setup an email address to be used with wordpress and the installation is able to send emails. The problem is with the subscription of users to the mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Jetpack's Subscriptions feature relies on WordPress.com. The emails sent via the feature are not sent from your own server, but from WordPress.com.

You will consequently want to contact the Jetpack support team [via this contact form](https://jetpack.com/contact-support/?rel=support). They are the only ones who can investigate more by looking at logs on WordPress.com. You will want to let them know your site URL, and you'll need to give them a few examples of the emails that did not receive a confirmation.

It's worth noting that those confirmation emails are only sent once. When a reader signs up to receive email notifications, they should receive one email. If they try to subscribe again later on, no new confirmation email will be sent.

A good first step for those folks is consequently to go to [subscribe.wordpress.com](https://subscribe.wordpress.com) to clear any pending subscriptions they may have.